# make `tar` archive from NTFS with non-ascii file names

Tags: tar, data-recovery, character-encoding, ntfs

Loaded a live disk into a Windows based machine with NTFS files.  Being a Linux user for some years, using `tar` came to my mind instantly and made some backup archives from partitions and stored them onto an NFS mounted partition on another machine.  Made System recovery by shipped disk with first machine and this deleted partitions, then I Changed partition table, and reformatted partitions (as NTFS again), and extracted `tar.gz` archives from NFS mounted partition into them. And noticed files with non-ascii names are missing.  Neither WinRar on windows doesn't show up those files.  I'm very sad because it's not my system and files were very important for owner.

What happened? Does tar (or gunzip) does have problems in reading from NTFS? Is there a chance I get files back from archive?

Answer (score 0):

I might try extracting the data files after booting back to windows using [windows tar](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm). If tar omitted some files while you were creating the archive, it probably would have given some error messages. Also, you can list the contents of a tar file with:

```
tar tvf tarfile.tar.gz
```

Comment: I'm sure `tar` didn't report any error